# $C^k$ map when fixing one variable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a $C^k$ map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Define a map $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0).$$

Must $g$ be a $C^k$ map?

I would think so, because if we differentiate $g$ a total of $k$ times (no matter with respect to which variables $x_i$'s), it's just the same as differentiating $f$ a total of $k$ times on the same sequence of variables, and then plugging in $x_{n+1}=0$. So if we get a continuous function for $f$, we also get a continuous function for $g$.

Is this reasoning rigorous? Are there other reasonings?

Comment: But doesn't $g$ map into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: @DBFdalwayse I defined $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not see that.

Comment: Then I think what you're asking is the same as asking if the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R^n$ is $C^k$ ; I think if $f$ is everywhere-differentiable, then it is definitely differentiable in the restricted set.

Comment: @DBFdalwayse I think I get the idea of what you're saying. But like my argument, it doesn't seem so "rigorous" (if you understand what I mean). Could you perhaps write up a rigorous argument as an answer, if you have one?

Comment: O.K, let me try it. I think you may also be able to compose the original function with a new function that is the identity in each component and ==$0$ in every other component.

Comment: Please let me know if you like my proof. I think it is pretty rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work:

Let $h$ be the function : $h(x_1,..,x_n):=(h_1,h_2,..,h_n)$=$(Id, Id,...,Id,0)$
$((x_1,x_2,..,x_n), (x_1,x_2,..,x_n),..,(x_1,x_2,..,x_n), (0,0,...,0))$ . Then $h$ is everywhere-differentiable,($C^{\infty}$, actually) and

$g=foh$ , so that $g$ is the composition of differentiable functions and therefore differentiable.

Comment: Honestly I'm confused. We're talking about $C^k$ functions, not just differentiable. Also I don't think $g=h\cdot f$ holds. Perhaps others will have some comment...

Comment: Well, h is the identity on each of $x_1,..,x_n$,respectively and it is a constant $0$ in $x_{n+1}$, and each of those is $C^{\infty}$. I think if you expand $f$ as $f_1,f_2,...$ it will be more clear. But it's up to you. Actually, I think I got the composition backwards; $g=f.h$

Comment: Thanks; sorry I could not make it more rigorous. I'll post if I can come up with something better.